# Clarify on a proof about normal domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a normal domain in which there is only one non-zero prime ideal, say $\mathfrak m$, and suppose that $\mathfrak m$ is finitely generated. Then $A$ is Noetherian and $\mathfrak m$ is principal.

Since all the prime ideals of $A$ are finitely generated by hypothesis, $A$ is Noetherian. In order to prove that $\mathfrak m$ is principal my teacher used the following argument.

> Call $k$  the field of fractions of $A$. Let $a\in \mathfrak m\setminus \{0\}$, and take the ideal $(a)$ generated by $a$; we have that  $\sqrt {(a)}=\mathfrak m $, and also that exixts $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\mathfrak m ^n$ is contained in $(a)$ but $\mathfrak m ^{n-1}$ is not. So exists a $b\in \mathfrak m ^{n-1}$ not divisible by $a$, and $\frac ba \in k$ is not an element of $A$, so $\frac ba$ is not integral over $A$ (since it is normal). Now call $\frac ba \mathfrak m$ the image of the multiplication by $\frac ba$ on $\mathfrak m$ in the field $k$, and assume (we proved separately but it's  not important in this context) that $\frac ba \mathfrak m\nsubseteq \mathfrak m$. Since $\mathfrak m^n \subseteq (a)$, any monomial of degree $\ge n$ in the generators of $\mathfrak m = (m_1, . . . , m_r)$ is divisible by $a$. *Then $b$ is a polynomial of degree $n − 1$ in the generators $\{m_i\}$* and, for
> all $i = 1 ,\dots , r$, we have $m_i\frac ba \in  A$, since $m_ib$ is of degree $n$ (divisible by $a$). Therefore $\frac ba \mathfrak m\subseteq A$. By the previous assumption $\frac ba \mathfrak m = A$, hence $1 = \ m \frac b
> a$ for some $m \in \mathfrak m$; so we have $(\frac  ab) \subseteq\mathfrak m$. Moreover, for every element $y \in \mathfrak m$, we have $y = (y\frac ba )\frac ab$ (and $y\frac ba  \in A$), so finally $(\frac ab) = m$.

My problem is that I don't understand why the part in italics is true: if any monomial  of degree $\ge n$ is divisible by $a$, it doesn't mean that any polynomial of degree $\ge n$ is divisible by  $a$. The fact that $b\in \mathfrak m^{n-1}$ is used to say that $b$ has degree $n-1$, but I really don't understand how to justify the part in italics.

Comment: I think a more accurate statement is that all monomials in $b$ are of degree $\geq n-1$. That should do the trick I think.

Comment: You could also just think of it as: $b \in \mathfrak{m}^{n-1}$ implies that $b\mathfrak{m} \subseteq \mathfrak{m}^n \subseteq (a)$ and then just divide through by $a$ to get $\frac{b}{a} \mathfrak{m}^{n-1} \subseteq A$.